# State list drawable not working properly on pre-honeycomb versions

Tags: android, listview, statelistdrawable

I'm making an application with checklists that primarily targets Android 4.0. There I use this selector as the background of my list item:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item
    android:state_pressed="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/checklist_selector_pressed" />

<item
    android:state_focused="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/checklist_selector_focused" />

<item
    android:state_activated="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/checklist_selector_selected" />

<item
    android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" />
```

"state_activated" seems to do the trick as the checked items do not stay visibly checked if I take that selector away. However, this only works on post-Honeycomb versions. Anything before that ignores state_activated (or state_checked and state_selected) and only accepts state_pressed (the lines color themselves when I touch them but do not stay colored afterwards). This is really confusing to me so I would appreciate any advice on the matter.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The `android:state_activated` attribute does not exist prior to Honeycomb. I suggest that you maintain two versions of the drawable: a default version in `res/drawable` that does not reference `android:state_activated` (or any other states that were introduced in Honeycomb) and a Honeycomb-and-later version in `res/drawable-v11` that does.

Comment: Thanks, I will certainly do that. What is the analog for android:state_activated in pre-Honeycomb versions, though? Meaning, how do I force checked items to have a certain drawable for their background? android:state_checked and android:state_selected don't seem to work.

Comment: @Gigen - `android:state_checked` should work (provided that the view is checkable -- you can experiment with that using the state identifier `android:state_checkable`). If it's not working, then perhaps the item order in your selector needs to be revised.